# Can Pandoc Ignore YAML Metadata Headers?

Tags: pandoc, metadata

Is there a way to get Pandoc to ignore YAML metadata headers? I have a batch of files that includes the headers, which are ordinarily lovely, but not needed for this particular output.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Pandoc not about LaTeX or TeX